# Dangling ssh sessions when my laptop goes to sleep

Tags: ssh, mac-osx, tcp

When I get up from my laptop (a Mac with MacOS Big Sur) for long enough that it "goes to sleep", my interactive sessions with ssh servers are broken. That is annoying but I could live with it. What is worse, though, is that the server side forked sshd processes seem to stick around forever, with the socket in the ESTABLISHED state. I really don't understand why -- I have set up both TCP keep alives and ssh protocol keep alives to fairly aggressive values with should expire shortly after the client goes Zzz. And they stay around even when shut down the laptop; I'll find them when I log in the next day.

So every time I log in, I have to go through a routine of `pgrep -u me sshd` and `kill -9` all of them except the current. It gets old. Can you give me a clue?